# Traduire « Jump the gun »

Tags: traduction, anglais, choix-de-mot

En anglais, « *to jump the gun* » veut dire agir prématurément.

Y a-t-il une expression en français qui a le même sens et qui rappelle une connotation similaire d'arme à feu ?

Comment: Je trouve que l'anglais n'a pas vraiment de connotation d'arme à feu.  L'expression anglaise fait plutôt allusion à un faux départ, le signal de départ d'une course à pied étant donné par un coup de feu.  Évidemment, cette question aurait beaucoup de pertinence pour une traduction littéraire, si le contexte faisait beaucoup de références aux armes à feu, par exemple.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Il y aurait bien "**brûler les étapes**" qui peut avoir un rapport avec les armes à feu et qui correspond bien au sens de l'expression "jump the gun".

Sinon, plus orienté armes à feu, il y a "**tirer plus vite que son ombre**", mais cette fois la signification est plus orienté sur la vitesse d'action que sur sa prématurité.

Answer (score 4):

Peut-être simplement "**se précipiter**".

Answer (score 2):

Il y aurait éventuellement **brûler (toutes) ses cartouches**, avec un sens au départ seulement voisin, mais parfois utilisé de manière identique.
Le sens initial de l'expression est d'avoir épuisé tous ses moyens d'action prématurément et de se retrouver par conséquent démuni. C'est pourquoi j'y vois une similarité, même sans équivalence littérale.

J'ignore si cela peut faire l'affaire dans ton contexte, mais je voulais le signaler.

---

Note : Très anecdotiquement car je sais que le sens en est très différent, mais citons une expression française qui pourrait passer pour un équivalent presque littéral de *jump the gun*, je veux parler de l'adjectif *saute-au-paf*, qui dans un registre très familier fait référence à une femme prompte à "griller toutes les étapes dans le processus de séduction"... attention donc à ce faux-ami ! (devrais-je dire cette fausse amie ?)

Answer (score 1):

Il y a aussi : *mettre la charrue avant les bœufs*

Answer (score 0):

Y'a toujours "sauter aux conclusions", mais pourquoi as-tu *explicitement* besoin de quelque chose qui référence les armes à feux?

Comment: Je trouve la connotation plus frappante. Sauter au conclusion apporte le même sense, mais je trouve l'expression plus douce.

Comment: L'*OP* n'a jamais dit qu'il avait *besoin* d'une référence aux armes à feu, mais a seulement demandé si une telle référence existait. Circeus, tu as sauté aux conclusions! :p

Comment: *Sauter aux conclusions* me semble être un anglicisme (en tout cas du point de vue de quelqu'un qui n'est pas québécois). [Quelques exemples de traductions](http://www.linguee.fr/anglais-francais/traduction/jump+to+conclusions.html).

Comment: @StéphaneGimenez Les anglicismes restent les mêmes d'une région à une autre. L'usage de ces anglicismes, par contre, diffère. Mais oui, [il s'agit d'un anglicisme](http://www.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/clefsfp/index-fra.html?lang=fra&lettr=indx_catlog_c&page=629.html#zz624) dans le cas présent.